# Applying a stylesheet to a notebook using a setterbar - palette hiccup

Tags: dynamic, stylesheet, palettes

I built a setterbar that allows me to quickly apply stylesheets to a notebook.  Here is the code:

```
SetterBar[Dynamic[temp], {"Lecture", "Testing"}],

Dynamic[If[temp == "Lecture",
  SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
   StyleDefinitions -> 
    "/Users/michaelmccain/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/\
StyleSheets/MyLectureStyles.nb"], 
  SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
   StyleDefinitions -> 
    "/Users/michaelmccain/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/\
StyleSheets/Testing.nb"]]]
```

When the code is located in the target notebook it works perfectly.  See gif below.

[image]

However, if I put the code above into a palette, then I get an annoying hiccup when I try and use it... The styles in the notebook don't update immediately. If I type at least one character in any cell, then the styles update.  Strange.  Below is gif illustrating the issue.

[image]

I'm not sure why. What is going on here?  Is there a fix you can think of?

Comment: A workaround is to add `NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[],""]` after `SetOptions[]`.  This resets everything.  I'm interested if anyone thinks this is a bug.

Comment: I've faced it too. I'm doing `SetOptions[nb, StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]` as an intermediate step and it works. That day it was one of minor problems so I forgot to report it. You can do that.